# how to add whitespace before and after in feature file + protractor + cucumber

Tags: protractor, cucumber, bdd, gherkin, feature-file

I need to add white space before and after my input value in feature file for example

| firstName |
| test |

the value retrieved from html is SPACEtestSPACE - note SPACE is actual space.

I tried giving it in single quotes like | ' test ' | but it didn't work as it is pulling the quotes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Adding spaces between "< and > " is enough to do it.

refer the console

[image]

Comment: vow! that was so simple. Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome Irfan. Can you please accept the answer and close this thread?

Comment: how do we accept the answer? I don't see any option.